# What is TIRHService.exe?

Tags: windows-server-2008, oracle, process, oracle-11g

What is this process?  It on a fresh install of Windows Server 2008 with an Oracle 11g database installed on it.  The process is in c:\windows\ and according to Sophos Anti-virus it is trying to access the registry.  It is probably harmless, but before I take it out of quarantine I'd like to know what it is. Google results only show it appearing in lists of processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at the google results for: TIRHService.exe ( Intuit Track-It! Remoting Helper (TIRemotingHelper))

It seems to be from Intuit Track-It program.  Track-It is a helpdesk program to create tickets, remote into the computer, etc... for businesses.

Comment: Thanks, that's it.  Our helpdesk uses that application.  I should have known.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing SysInternals' [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), and watching what parts of registry is the service trying to access.

Comment: I'm monitoring it, but haven't seen any activity yet.